# How to copy development db to test db in mongodb rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am using Mogodb in my rails app as my database how take the snap of my development db and stick to my test db in local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongo console `db.copyDatabase('bd_dev', 'bd_test')`